# How to use conditional commands inside the switch in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I wrote a program that by pressing the `ArrowUp` button I want to first check the `mode` inside
Print the `switch` according to the `mode` on the console
And I have a `button` to change the `mode`
I do not know why the conditional statement inside the `switch` does not work
I also want the switch to be inside `useEffect`
please guide me

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [mode, setMode] = useState("one");

  useEffect(() => {
    const keyDownCallback = function (e) {
      switch (e.keyCode) {
        case 38:
          mode === "one" ? console.log("one") : console.log("two");
          break;
      }
    };
    document.addEventListener("keydown", keyDownCallback);
    return () => document.removeEventListener("keydown", keyDownCallback);
  }, []);
  
  function handleChangeMode() {
    return mode === "one" ? setMode("two") : setMode("one");
  }

  return (
    <div style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
      <h2>View the output on the console</h2>
      <button onClick={handleChangeMode}>change mode</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Switch is working fine for me. checkout here - https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-meadow-ef8fw9?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited: [Working example with minimal changes](https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-sara-n5lkoc?file=/src/App.js) for you new code.
The only thing I changed was to add `[mode]`to useEffect

You declare a the function `keyDownCallback` in useEffect that is never used.
That is why you don't get your prints.

Comment: I edited my code, the problem remains

Comment: Add mode as a dependency in use effect. 
[Working example with minimal changes](https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-sara-n5lkoc?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: No, now it only prints the same and does not change when the printing mode is changed

Comment: @goodboy see my updated answer with a sandbox

Answer (score 0):

The switch case works fine, the problem is the way you are using useEffect.
You need to add a dependency for mode in order to be able to switch modes and print accordingly. Also providing a default case is crucial.
https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-https-6ol4zw?file=/src/App.js

And in case you want the mode to toggle with every click, you can simply move the toggling logic inside the listener's callback function.
https://codesandbox.io/s/winter-haze-29inyy?file=/src/App.js